# WebRequest.GetResponse(): read response, even on a 401?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I'm having trouble with the authorization piece of a third-party API.  The API is shooting me a 401 in the HTTP Status Code, and more info in the response body.

```
   var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
   req.Method = "GET";

   var resp = req.GetResponse();
```

This is the code I typically use, but GetResponse() throws an exception on the 401 and I never get the response body.

Is there another implementation of this request I'm missing, or another way to do this in .NET so that I can get the response even when the request generates a 401?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[web exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8)

The `WebException` contains a `Response` object that you can use to read the response body

Comment: Oh, duh.  Looked everywhere but the exception itself.  Thank you.